# How to Read a SortedList from a File?

Tags: c#, collections, .net

I have a SortedList, the key is Contact.name and the value, is an object, Contact. I´m writing this list to a file, with BinaryWriter and I don´t have any trouble but now I want to read this list, and after, look for an specific contact. I don´t know how to do it. I think that I must read the file and after that look for the contact, but how can I fill the SortedList with the binary code saved in the file?

Comment: This Sounds like a Dictionary, do you have any code?

Comment: It´s a PDA with phone numbers, adresses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example on how to do, both, read and write from a binary file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        WriteContacts(new List<Contact>( new []{ new Contact { ID = 1, Name = "Juan", Age = 34 }, new Contact { Name = "Pedro", Age = 23, ID = 2 } }));
        FindContactInFile("Juan");
        FindContactInFile("Mario");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void FindContactInFile(string name)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (Stream s = new FileStream("contacts.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            var contacts = (List<Contact>)formatter.Deserialize(s);
            var person  = contacts.Where(x=>x.Name==name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (person != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Persona encontrada: {0}", person.Name);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("{0} no fue encontrado en el archivo.", name);
        }
    }

    private static void WriteContacts(List<Contact> contacts)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream s = new FileStream("contacts.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(s, contacts);
        }
    }
}
[Serializable]
class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Many things can be improved there, like not reading the entire file every time you search for someone. Or not reading the entire file at once to begin with... In any case, the key concept here is that in order to store something in a binary file you need to serialize the object. For this you can use one of the BinaryFormatters provided by .NET (as I did above) and to read back from the file, you simply do the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want `BinaryReader` which will take the File output from `BinaryWriter` and deserialize into your original type.

[This is a good example of using both on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx)